understanding middleware callback
function authenticateJwt(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log(`information err ` + info);

    const boomErr  = boom.unauthorized();
    if(err || !user || user !== `object`){
        return next(boomErr);
    }else{
        return next(req);
    }
    })(req, res, next)
  };

  module.exports = authenticateJwt;

I don't understand but why use (req, res, next) in the line 11 ?, the functions returns implicit ?.
what book explain  this implementation ?

You should read the documentation of Express, it's explained there.

ahhh (req, res, next) invokes the middleware function returned by passport.authenticate() with req and res as arguments to the middleware function.  thanks
